# How can I check if two lists are equals?

Tags: java, list

I have to solve one problem, I don't know the reason why my code doesn't work.
I have to check if two lists I created are completely equals so they have the same value at the same position.
I'm allowed to use loops as well, even by I prefer the recursive mode.
Thank you so much for your help and time!

```
public static boolean checkEquality(Node n, Node m) {
        if(n != null && m != null) {
            boolean res = false;
            while(n!=null) {
                if(n.getElem()==m.getElem()) {
                    n = n.getNext();
                    m = m.getNext();
                    res = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    res = false;
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Lists empty!");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well for starters, consider the case where one list is empty and one is not. You consider those to be equal at the moment.

Comment: I edit the code, now is correct.

Comment: So you never call `m.getNext()`? You only ever compare against the first element?

Comment: `getElem()` returns a primitive value?

Comment: You should `break` as soon as you find 2 that aren't equal. Otherwise, this will say they match even if all but the last are unequal. (But there is still the issue you only call `n = n.getNext();` when 2 are equal).

Comment: No i just check the first list, and getElem returns an int

Comment: Ok I put as well: m = m.getNext(); But the problem is that it doesnt even enter inside the if

Comment: a) The calls to `next` should be outside of the `if/else`. b) [What is the difference between == and equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520464)

Comment: Just debug your code, SO is not a debugging service. Just step through line by line. If you don't know how - add println statements.

Comment: HINT for the others looking at this: on a mismatch, the pointers aren't advanced, so it hangs forever. The most direct of a few problems here.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of weak spots, so I give the solid solution:

```
public static boolean checkEquality(Node n, Node m) {
    while (n != null && m != null) {
        //if (!Objects.equals(n.getElem(), m.getElem())) {
        if (n.getElem() != m.getElem()) {
            return false;
        }
        n = n.getNext();
        m = m.getNext();
    }
    return n == null && m == null;
}
```

- Comparing can only be done while both `n` and `m` are not null. Your code only checks `n`.
- `==` is not valid for instance for String. Instead of `.equals` one might also use `Objects.equals` which also tests for `null`.
- `getNext` in every loop step.
- two empty lists are also equal. Both lists should end at the same time.

The tst fails as soon as two compared nodes are not equal. So one should start with assuming a `true` result. And as soon as the comparison fails, one should no longer loop and certainly not overwrite `res` from false to true.

Comment: The problem I saw on my code by printing is that it doesnt even enter in the if.. I do not understand whats wrong..

Comment: What are the elements? If `int` or some primitive type then `==` is correct. If `String` or some other class then `x.equals(y)` is needed..

Comment: I did it, it literally does not enter into the if. It's like it doesn't read it.

Comment: Then you need to debug it, or do `System.out.println(n.getElem());` and such.

Answer (score 0):

it would help if you elaborate what type of list u are comparing,
linkedlist or arrays. based on your function, it seems that you are planning to compare a linkedlist.

- [linkedlist documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/identical-linked-lists/)
- [arrays documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-arrays-equals-java-examples/)

```
   // sample comparison
   boolean areIdentical(Node a_head, Node b_head) {
        Node a = a_head, b = b_head;
        while (a != null && b != null) {
            if (a.data != b.data)
                return false;
 
            /* If we reach here, then a and b are not null
               and their data is same, so move to next nodes
               in both lists */
            a = a.next;
            b = b.next;
        }
 
        // If linked lists are identical, then 'a' and 'b'
        // must be null at this point.
        return (a == null && b == null);
    }
```